# RavenDB RQL GoupBy Support

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have a requirement to retrieve data from RavenDB by using `groupby`. I am not sure how to apply the query in RavenDB using RQL.

The similar query for SQL Server has been provided, please help me to provide an equivalent RQL Query Statement.

SQL Query **"Select count() as Count, key() as UserId from UserTraces where TimeStamp > fromdate and TimeStamp < todate
group by UserId"**

Thanks

Comment: You need to define a Map-Reduce Index. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59949503/5737562